# Como solucionar erro "3183" ao importar um banco no SQLSERVER 2012

Tags: sql, banco-de-dados, sql-server

Boa tarde! Pra começar, aviso que sou leiga no assunto.
Preciso rodar um banco local na minha máquina para poder trabalhar em um projeto.

Instalei os programas:
SQLSERVER Express 2012
SQL Management Studio 2012

Uso um Macbook Pro e rodo uma VM de Win7 através do Paralells.

O banco de dados que me enviaram tem 8GB e as orientações foram pra renomear o arquivo para .dmp e rodar a query:

```
RESTORE DATABASE meu_banco
    FROM DISK = N'C:\meu_banco.dmp'
WITH REPLACE,
MOVE 'vod_muzika' TO 'C:\sqlserver\meu_banco.mdf',
MOVE 'vod_muzika_log' TO 'C:\sqlserver\meu_banco.ldf'
GO
```

Porém me retorna o erro:

> Msg 3183, Level 16, State 2, Line 1 RESTORE detected an error on page
>   (8192:536879104) in database "vod_muzika" as read from the backup set.
>   Msg 3013, Level 16, State 1, Line 1 RESTORE DATABASE is terminating
>   abnormally.

Pelo o que pesquisei na internet, parece que o banco está corrompido.
Sendo que eu já baixei esse banco 4x e outras pessoas baixaram o mesmo banco e conseguiram importar sem problemas. O erro é só comigo.

Existe alguma outra possibilidade sem ser o banco corrompido e como poderia resolver?

**ATUALIZAÇÃO**

Seguindo a dica do amigo Reginaldo, fiz o seguinte:

```
RESTORE DATABASE meu_banco 
FROM DISK = N'C:\meu_banco.dmp'
WITH CONTINUE_AFTER_ERROR, REPLACE,
MOVE 'meu_banco' TO 'C:\sqlserver\vod_muzika.mdf',
MOVE 'meu_banco_log' TO 'C:\sqlserver\vod_muzika.ldf';
GO
```

Tentei com WITH RECOVERY também e tive o seguinte erro:

> Location:  gfh.cpp:2911 Expression:    rec.Size () < MAX_PROPERTY_ROW_LENGTH SPID:         52 Process ID:  1820 Msg 3013, Level
>   16, State 1, Line 2 RESTORE DATABASE is terminating abnormally. Msg
>   3624, Level 20, State 1, Line 2 A system assertion check has failed.
>   Check the SQL Server error log for details. Typically, an assertion
>   failure is caused by a software bug or data corruption. To check for
>   database corruption, consider running DBCC CHECKDB. If you agreed to
>   send dumps to Microsoft during setup, a mini dump will be sent to
>   Microsoft. An update might be available from Microsoft in the latest
>   Service Pack or in a QFE from Technical Support.

Answer (score 1):

Sim esta corrompido. Você deve perder alguma coisa. Para continuar a restauração mesmo após o erro use

```
RECOVER DATABASE ... WITH CONTINUE_AFTER_ERROR
```

O banco ficará em `SUSPECT` após a restauração e você poderá tentar repara-lo.

Comment: Reginaldo, obrigada pela resposta. Esse comando RECOVER dá erro de sintaxe. Troquei o RECOVER pelo RESTORE com o CONTINUE_AFTER_ERROR e deu erro ....

Comment: Você tem espaço no disco temporário para fazer o restore?

Comment: "A system assertion check has failed. Check the SQL Server error log for details. Typically, an assertion failure is caused by a software bug or data corruption. To check for database corruption, consider running DBCC CHECKDB. If you agreed to send dumps to Microsoft during setup, a mini dump will be sent to Microsoft. An update might be available from Microsoft in the latest Service Pack or in a QFE from Technical Support. "

Comment: Como você utilizou o comando?

Comment: Tenho espaço sim. Fiz o seguinte: RESTORE DATABASE meu_banco
  FROM DISK = N'C:\meu_banco.dmp'
WITH CONTINUE_AFTER_ERROR,
MOVE 'meu_banco' TO 'C:\sqlserver\meu_banco.mdf',
MOVE 'meu_banco_log' TO 'C:\sqlserver\meu_banco.ldf'
GO

Comment: Uma parte do erro que esqueci de botar aí "Expression:  rec.Size () < MAX_PROPERTY_ROW_LENGTH"